# Classification Library

Tags: c#, java, c++, python, machine-learning

I need to test various famous classification methods like kNN, ID3 and ... on a huge data-set of a project, and choose one for future use.

I have no limitation on language but performance and readable code both in learning and classification phase are very important.

therefore, I'm looking for a good library with following features:

- includes various classification methods
- high performance
- easily usable

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [RapidMiner](http://rapid-i.com/) which comes with a Java-API and graphical tools for data mining. The community edition is free, I think.

I used the predecessor of this tool/library as a student but do not have professional experience with it, though.

Answer (score 1):

You shuold take a look at [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/), a great machine learning module for Python. Can't tell you much about it, because I never really used it (just read about it and looked at several projects solved with it), but it seems to be very good.

You may also want to take a look at this list of Python machine learning modules:
http://web.media.mit.edu/~stefie10/technical/pythonml.html

Or at this SO question:
[Is there a recommended package for machine learning in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289920/is-there-a-recommended-package-for-machine-learning-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) - it is written in python and has variety classifiers and also metods for testing them.